# Of the following which would you consider the most common Arabic form of language used

Tags: arabic, writing-system-choice

I am in need to translating a site of mine and I need to add Arabic. According to the [language code](http://www.lingoes.net/en/translator/langcode.htm) there are several forms. Which of these would you consider to be the most "common" type?

```
ar-AE   Arabic (U.A.E.)
ar-BH   Arabic (Bahrain)
ar-DZ   Arabic (Algeria)
ar-EG   Arabic (Egypt)
ar-IQ   Arabic (Iraq)
ar-JO   Arabic (Jordan)
ar-KW   Arabic (Kuwait)
ar-LB   Arabic (Lebanon)
ar-LY   Arabic (Libya)
ar-MA   Arabic (Morocco)
ar-OM   Arabic (Oman)
ar-QA   Arabic (Qatar)
ar-SA   Arabic (Saudi Arabia)
ar-SY   Arabic (Syria)
ar-TN   Arabic (Tunisia)
ar-YE   Arabic (Yemen)
```

Comment: Welcome to Language Learning Stack Exchange! This is a site about learning and teaching languages; please review [what is on-topic on this site](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Centre. I'm afraid I need to close this question as off-topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ar-EG   Arabic (Egypt)`

The Egyptian dialect is the most common for two reasons. First, it's the [largest Arabic-speaking country](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_countries_where_Arabic_is_an_official_language) in the world. Second, it's the main producer of [Arabic language entertainment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cinema_of_Egypt) (tv, movies, music).

Keep in mind, though, that written Arabic is almost always Modern Standard Arabic (MSA), which is not on your list.

Comment: Please don't answer questions that are off-topic; this just attracts more questions that are off-topic and harms the quality of our site.

Comment: @Christophe I answered it before it was off topic.

Comment: It was off-topic when it was posted. As a participant with more than 2,000 reps, you should have enough experience to judge whether a question is blatantly off-topic or not. (There are edge cases, but this question is not one of them.)

Comment: Knowing the most common form of Arabic could inform a language learner's decision and actions, thus I did not consider it off-topic before you officially declared it so. People have different opinions.

Comment: It is clear that the information *can be used* that way, but the *question itself* needs to be on topic. And the ISO language tags are totally irrelevant on this site.